# How to get certain item from grouped arraylist android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have such filtered arraylist:

```
val tess = questionArrayList.filter { model -> model.id in answeredQuestions }
val array2: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
for (i in tess.indices) {
    array2.add(tess[i].tasks_group!!)
}
```

then I group it:

```
val variable = array2.groupingBy { i: Int -> i }.eachCount()
```

and I need to get items of `variable` which count is == 3. I tried to do it like this:

```
if (variable.containsValue(3)){

}
```

but I don't know how to get certain item. It means that I need keys of items whose value is 3. I tried also do it by loop but I didn't manage to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val withValue3 = variable.filterValues { value -> value == 3 } 
if (withValue3.isNotEmpty()) { 
    //...
}
```

or

```
if (variable.containsValue(3)) {
    val withValue3 = variable.filterValues { value -> value == 3 }
}
```